# Как получить текст запроса при серверной ошибке?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'post.php',
    data: '&param=' + param,
    success: function(response){
        try { 
            response = jQuery.parseJSON(response); 
        } catch (e) { 
            console.log(param);
        }
        console.log('ok');
    }
});
```

Если таких запросов много и одновременно, то велика вероятность, что param при ошибке уже будет не тем, что был отправлен в запросе.
Вопрос такой: как при ошибке получить ровно то значение param какое было отправленно этим запросом?

Желательно без оборачивания и без того много-вложенного ajax'са в

```
(function(param) {
    // здесь param не будет изменяться извне
})(param);
```

Comment: сделайте себе внутри `let tmp = param` и все, или нет? вообще обычно не требуется дополнительно парсить ответ, jquery сама это делает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В контексте выполнения функции `success()` ключевое слово `this` будет указывать на объект, который вы передали функции `$.ajax()`. Вы можете сделать так:

```
console.log(this.data);
// вернет строку '&param=${param}, 
// где ${param} – значение переменной param в момент вызова функции $.ajax()
```

Или даже определить свое свойство, например `my_param`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'post.php',
    data: '&param=' + param,
    my_param: param,                                // ← определили
    success: function(response){
        try { 
            response = jQuery.parseJSON(response); 
        } catch (e) { 
            console.log(this.my_param);             // ← используем
        }
        console.log('ok');
    }
});
```